Blazor: El entorno de desarrollo no debe estar habilitado para aplicaciones implementadas
Estoy haciendo el chat en tiempo real con Blazor y SignalR de la documentación de Microsoft y me da Error al desplegar la aplicación en IIS 10.0 Windows Server 2019
Ya probe mi código localmente y todo funcionó correctamente, pero cuando intento desplegar mi aplicación a un servidor IIS la aplicación me muestra este error.

Ya probe con habilitar el entorno de desarrollo pero esto no soluciono el problema.
